# MagicZoomPlus:Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getShowSwatchTooltip() module-swatches/view/frontend/templates/product/view/renderer.phtml

Tags: php, xml, magento, magento2, magiczoomplus

MagicZoomPlus:Fatal error-Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getShowSwatchTooltip() module-swatches/view/frontend/templates/product/view/renderer.phtml
file:catalog_product_view_type_configurable

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.options.wrapper">
            <block class="MagicToolbox\MagicZoomPlus\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable" name="product.info.options.configurable" as="options_configurable" before="-" template="Magento_ConfigurableProduct::product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml"/>
            <block class="MagicToolbox\MagicZoomPlus\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable" name="product.info.options.swatches" as="swatch_options" before="-" />
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Problem Due to Upgrade of Magento Version Absence of ViewModel

Comment: I have faced same issue after upgrade Magento 2.3.4. Have you got the solution ?

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to the newest version of the MagicZoomPlus module?

Comment: @KirtiNariya you have to fix this issue? I have also face the same issue after Magento upgrade from 2.3 to 2.4.3

Answer (score 0):

<sup>This answer was exerted from the question itself</sup>

---

Solution 1:Edit the Same File

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.options.wrapper">
            <block class="MagicToolbox\MagicZoomPlus\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable" name="product.info.options.configurable" as="options_configurable" before="-" template="Magento_ConfigurableProduct::product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml"/>
            <referenceBlock class="MagicToolbox\MagicZoomPlus\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable" name="product.info.options.swatches" />
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Solution 2: Create a new module override layout

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.options.configurable" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.options.wrapper">
            <referenceBlock name="product.info.options.swatches" remove="true"/>
            <block class="MagicToolbox\MagicZoomPlus\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable" name="product.info.options.swatches.modified"
                   as="swatch_options_modied" before="-">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="configurable_view_model"
                              xsi:type="object">Codilar\MagicZoomPlus\ViewModel\Configurable</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```